# Subnet vs Subsequence

Tags: general-topology

In topological space $X$, $X$ is compact iff every net has covergent subnet. It is true that a sequence is a net, so why we can't derive sequentially compact from compact?

Comment: Because there are compact spaces which are not sequentially compact!

Comment: A sequence has subnets that are not subsequences.

Comment: You can find examples in the relevant Wikipedia page.

Comment: @menag why? could u please tell me?

Comment: @89085731 A subnet can have a totally different index set, even uncountable, even thought the original net has a countable index set. A net is not a set of points, it's the *mapping* from an index set to the space. People often confuse a sequence and the set of points of a sequence, and the same with nets.